# What should I do to become a commercial pilot?

Tags: career

I am 25 years old, I have completed my bachelor  degree  from electrical  engineering. So what should I do to become a pilot?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might want to look at our existing [career questions](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) and it would be good to know which country you're in. It's often difficult to answer career questions because there are so many personal, financial and legal variables, so the more specific you can be, the better.

Comment: I am from Bangladesh,  I am asking here that, do I eligible for that? what are the main factor to become commercial  pilot.

Comment: The main factor in becoming a pilot is.... Pilot training! You need to find a good local flying school. I have found 4 flying schools in Bangladesh already by doing a Google search.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to train and fly in the US...

You should spend that money on an MSE or MBA, get your private/instrument, and then buy your own plane and fly whenever you want.

However, if you feel you must become a commercial pilot you should find a local flight school and lay out a plan with someone who has authourity to negotiate pricing.

-lay out your objective.  You are paying for a private license, instrument, all of the time building for commercial, and then commercial.  That's a minimum of 250 flight hours plus a lot of billable hours for a very lucky CFI.  You can negotiate an awesome rate if you guarantee the school that business in s short amount of time.

-DO NOT pre-pay more than $1000 at a time.  Keeping funds on account is fine, just don't give them more than you're comfortable losing if suddenly they close.  It happens.

-stick to a schedule.  Fly a lot.  It's cheaper to knock it all out at once.  You have to relearn stuff if you only fly once or twice a week.

-don't get caught up comparing part 61 and part 141 schools.  Just go with the most affordable option.

-research airline minimums.  A commercial cert won't necessarily get you a job.  If fact, a commercial cert means very little wothout hours to go with it.  Think about adding a CFI cert to your shopping list.